# Uploading an image from a flutter app to a webserver results in a corrupted file

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to download a png image from a nginx webserver to a Flutter app and then immediately upload the bytes to a different directory on the same webserver. In the log run, the image will be altered in the app, but the issue arises already without any local modifications.

The image is successfully downloaded with the following function and then displayed.

```
Future<Uint8List> fetchImage(imageUrl) async {
  var url = Uri.parse(imageUrl);

  final response =
      await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return response.bodyBytes;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load image');
  }
}
```

While the upload itself works with the following function and the file is successfully created on the web server, the image can no longer be opened when accessed via SFTP. The file is the same size as the original, or sometimes 1 kB bigger.

```
pushImage(Uint8List imageBytes, String filename) async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://example.org/output/$filename');

  var request = http.MultipartRequest("PUT", url);

  request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('img', imageBytes,
      filename: filename, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')));

  request.send().then((response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200)
      print("Uploaded!");
    else
      print(response.statusCode);
  });
}
```

I tend to rule out any issues with the server or proxy configuration since the upload from a test tool (insomnia) to the webserver works perfectly fine.

I was suspecting an issue with the contentType/MediaType, but other people seem to be able to use this configuration successfully.